# Ethernet Connection

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

Loaded up Ubuntu 20.04.4.
Have static IP configured.
Removed monitor, mouse and keyboard to make a stand alone server.
When I remove the usb items, the network disconnects.
Noticed when the server boots up with everything connected
the ethernet connection will be green for a bit, then nothing and finally red.
Any idea why I am seeing this behavior?
Tom

Comment: Look at the network logs: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: I entered the above and received a response that there are no entries???

Comment: Is this a server or desktop install? What if you leave only the monitor connected ?

Comment: Server Ubuntu 20.04.4 Server install

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a driver issue, as if the system thinks the usb devices are external usb nic devices. You might wanna check all your logs.. https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/logwatch - tool I found to be super helpful.

Comment: Hello. Not an answer.